# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined state object inside array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, undefined

State Object inside array order_trans map error

```
this.state = {
    order: {
        "id": 2,
        "order_trans": [
            {
                "id": 2,
                "order_payment_id": "61023184-4ee7-4b8d-80c7-b593b994607f",
                "order_amount": 11628.0,
                "signature": "TSbSYzqNcT3PD7sgu4KGpuTsgIPzumTeg753iswBGsw=",
                "created_at": "2020-10-29T16:13:22.158603Z",
                "updated_at": "2020-10-29T16:13:22.158630Z",
                "buyer": 20,
                "order": 2
            }
        ],
        "order_token": "61023184-4ee7-4b8d-80c7-b593b994607f",
        "grand_total": 11628.0,
        "name": "Achu",
        "land_mark": "",
        "created_at": "2020-10-29T16:12:31.291014Z",
        "updated_at": "2020-10-29T16:12:31.291035Z",
        "buyer": 20
    }
    }
```

when loop inside state object array

```
{this.state.order.order_trans.map((p) => (
                    <p>{p.id}</p>
                ))}
```

i get error TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Comment: Looks correct. Could you please include some more info ?

Comment: just try `this.state.order?.order_trans?.map`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are updating the state after rendering. In that case, just make sure that the `order_trans` value is present in the state. You can do the following,

```
{this.state.order && this.state.order.order_trans && this.state.order.order_trans.map((p) => (
                <p>{p.id}</p>
            ))}
```

Or you can use the new optional chaining operator,

```
{ this.state.order?.order_trans.map((p) => (
                <p>{p.id}</p>
            ))}
```